# How to set a layout to ocupy the entire window in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Here is my FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox prefHeight="Infinity" prefWidth="936.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Files…" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save As…" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About This App" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
      <HBox maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" prefHeight="429.0" prefWidth="1048.0">
         <children>
            <StackPane prefHeight="Infinity" prefWidth="681.0">
               <children>
                  <ListView maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" prefHeight="Infinity" prefWidth="690.0" />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Files...">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </StackPane>
            <VBox prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="130.0">
               <children>
                  <ImageView accessibleRoleDescription="Preview" accessibleText="Preview" fitHeight="172.0" fitWidth="364.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
                  <VBox prefHeight="78.0" prefWidth="48.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Move Down" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Move Up" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Remove" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </HBox>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

When I resize the window the `ListView` does not cover all the screen:

[image: My Output]

I want it to stick to the bottom of the screen when I resize it. Is there any attribute that could do that for me? And on which element should I apply it? If my FXML is too long, use a simple one to explain how to do it.

Comment: What about `layout.prefHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty())`?

Comment: Wrap your `VBox` in an `AnchorPane` and anchor your `VBox` to it.

Comment: Add a `VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"` attribute to the `HBox` element containing the `ListView`. If you also want the `ListView` to grow horizontally add an `HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"` attribute to the `ListView` element.

Comment: You're hardcoding the height of the `HBox` containing the `ListView`, so of course it won't grow when you increase the height of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hard-code widths (and heights) of elements, you can't expect them to be resized by the layout pane. Remove *all* hardcoded widths and heights; the only exceptions are if you have elements (such as the buttons) whose default `maxWidth` is `Region.USE_PREF_SIZE`, and you want them to be able to grow; here you can set the `maxWidth` to `Infinity`. Then configure your layout panes to allow them to lay things out the way you actually want.

The following does what I think you are trying to do:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Files…" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save As…" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About This App" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
      <HBox VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <StackPane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <ListView />
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Files...">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </StackPane>
            <VBox HBox.hgrow="NEVER" fillWidth="false">
               <children>
                  <ImageView accessibleRoleDescription="Preview" accessibleText="Preview" fitHeight="172.0" fitWidth="364.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
                  <VBox fillWidth="true">
                     <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Move Down" maxWidth="Infinity" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Move Up"  maxWidth="Infinity" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Remove"  maxWidth="Infinity" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </HBox>
  </children>
</VBox>
```